# Stop child components from re rendering with context subscription

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a higher-order component that takes children and then re-renders them based on the state of a context provider.

Consider the following simplified example:

index.js

```
const ChildElem = () => {
   return(
     <div/>
   )
}

class Example extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <FocusProvider>
          <ChildElem/>
          <ChildElem/>
          <ChildElem/>
        </FocusProvider>
      )
   }
}
```

FocusProvider.js

```
class FocusProvider extends React.Component{
   renderChildren = (providerState) => {
      //Does nothing with state and simply returns children yet they still re render
      return this.props.children
   }

   render(){
      return(
        <Provider>
           <Subscribe to={[ContextProvider]}>
             {provider => this.renderChildren(provider.state)}
           </Subscribe>
        </Provider>
      )
   }
}
```

As you can see from the example the children of `FocusProvider` are being returned from a function that subscribes to a context.

The problem I am running into is that the children are being re-rendered even though nothing is being changed on them. The only thing that is being changed is the state of the context provider they are subscribed to.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can control whether the component should update or not there is a function of react component class

```
shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState, nextContext ) {
/* compare nextState with your current states properties if you want to update on any basis return true if you want to render the component again  */
return true; // will re-render component , 
return false; // do not re-render component even if you change component states properites
}
```

nextProps contains that prop the new props , and nextState contain new State properties

Comment: using the `shouldComponentUpdate` method on `FocusProvider` or even the `ChildElem` components seems to have no effect

Comment: depending upon the nextProps and nextStates , if you do not want to re-render the component return false from shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: Try memoizing your render function with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).